# How is $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,R)$ defined in a simple manner as an R-module?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homological-algebra, free-modules

Wishing to understand the **universal coefficient formula** for homology modules, I came across this new space $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}$ that I presume that it can be viewed as an $R$-module, and I do not understand how its elements look like, how the addition operation is defined, the scalar multiplication a

The formula is:

> **Corollary $7.57$.** *If $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is an abelian group, then, for all $n \geq 0$,*
>
> $$H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} A \ \oplus \ \text{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(H_{n-1}(X),A).$$

**My question is**: Is it possible to define in a concrete way (*I am not an algebrist and I do not want to use a lot of specialized concepts in order to define it*) the $R$-module $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,R)$ for a given $R$-module $X$, with $R$ a **principal ideal domain**?

I found in the book *Mac Lane-Homology, page 150* and in the book of *Rotman-An introduction to homological algebra, page 412* the following definition which is not so clear for me:

> There are other constructions of Tor. For example, $\text{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ can be defined by generators and realtions. Consider all triples $(a,n,b)$, where $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $na=0$, and $nb=0$; then $\text{Tor}_1^\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ is generated by all such triples subject to the relations (whenever both sides are defined)
>
> $$(a+a',n,b) = (a,n,b) + (a',n,b)$$
> $$(a,n,b+b') = (a,n,b) + (a,n,b')$$
> $$(ma,n,b) = (a, mn, b) = (a, m, nb)$$

In this definition we see only an **abelian group**, but I want to see it as an R-module. Can someone please help me, maybe with an easy example, to understand the construction of $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,R)$ as an R-module?

Comment: In the universal coefficient formula, $T(A, B) = {\rm Tor}_1^R(A, B)$ involves $R$-modules $A$ and $B$, and it is itself an $R$-module. (In the corollary you wrote, $R$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$.) It can be defined as the left-derived functor $T(\cdot, B) = L^1 {\rm Tor}(\cdot, B)$, but for computations you can probably just get away with the relation $T(\mathbb{Z}, B) = 0$ and $T(\mathbb{Z}_n, B) = \{x\in B:\, nx = 0\}$ for $n\not = 0$, along with additivity: $T(A\oplus A', B) = T(A, B) \oplus T(A', B)$.

Comment: [Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/451674/19965).  Please note that is considered bad form to crosspost without some mitigating factor. If you do decide to crosspost for any reason, you should link the questions together to get advice on the matter.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for this site than math-overflow. Regardless, you shouldn't post to both.

Comment: @anomaly Sorry. I deleted it from Mathoverflow. Can it be defined wihout the use of the left derived functor? I want something as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. Hatcher has an ad hoc construction over a couple of pages, but he's really just defining one particular derived functor without using the name. Fundamentally, you're looking at the failure of the right-exact functor $-\otimes_ B$ to be exact, and that's exactly what a derived functor measures. I think there might be a treatment in the appendix of Eisenbud that just sticks to $R = \mathbb{Z}$, at least.

Comment: Oops, sloppy mathing: I meant $L^1 {\rm Hom}(\cdot, B)$ above, not $L^1 {\rm Tor}(\cdot, B)$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @anomaly I didn't find such thing in Eisenbud book appendix. Just some exercises about Tor. What about the definition that I gave in the statement of my question? I didn't know how to use it even for proving that $Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,\mathbb{Z}_n)=\{x\in X\ |\ nx=0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me mention that $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(-,-)$ is an operation that eats two $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (read: abelian groups) and outputs a new $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So when you ask for $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ to be an $R$-module, it's not clear what you mean. What *is* true is that $\text{Tor}^R$ exists for any ring $R$, and $\text{Tor}^R(-,-)$ eats two $R$-modules and spits out a new $R$-module. This is probably the level of generality that you're thinking of.

Now, $\text{Tor}$ has lots of interesting properties, relating it to other branches of math, and because of this it has many applications (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCm-FheTyp8), for example), but it sounds like you're primarily interested in *computing* $\text{Tor}$ so that you can use it for the universal coefficient theorem. Let's start by giving a few important properties of $\text{Tor}$ that will use used *all the time* in computations:

1. $\text{Tor}^R(A,B) \cong \text{Tor}^R(B,A)$
2. $\text{Tor}^R(A, \bigoplus_\alpha B_\alpha) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha \text{Tor}^R(A, B_\alpha)$
3. $\text{Tor}^R(\bigoplus_\alpha A_\alpha, B) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha \text{Tor}^R(A_\alpha, B)$

Now let's start with homology with coefficients in an abelian group. So we've computed $H_n(X)$, the homology groups with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, and we *want* to compute $H_n(X,A)$, the homology groups with coefficients in some abelian group $A$. The universal coefficient theorem says that

$$
H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} A \ \oplus \ \text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(H_{n-1}(X), A)
$$

Since we're working over $\mathbb{Z}$, let me mention two more useful facts for computation in this special case:

4. $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z},B) \cong 0$ for every $B$
5. $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/n, B) \cong \{ b \in B \mid nb = 0 \}$

In particular, note that $5$ implies $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/m, \mathbb{Z}/n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)$.

Now, in some sense, this is almost everything you need to know! After all, *every* finitely generated abelian group looks like $\mathbb{Z}^n \oplus \bigoplus_k \mathbb{Z}/n_k$. So the above properties guarantee that we can compute $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ for any two finitely generated abelian groups $A$ and $B$ by splitting up the direct sums, then using $4$ and $5$ to compute the pieces. For example:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3, \ \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4  \right )
&\overset{2}{\cong}
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3, \ \mathbb{Z} \right )
\oplus
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3, \ \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\\
&\overset{4}{\cong}
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3, \ \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\\
&\overset{3}{\cong}
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\oplus
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\oplus
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\oplus
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}/3, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\\
&\overset{4}{\cong}
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\oplus
\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z} \left ( \mathbb{Z}/3, \mathbb{Z}/4 \right )
\\
&\overset{5}{\cong}
\mathbb{Z}/\gcd(2,4) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/\gcd(3,4)
\\
&\cong
\mathbb{Z}/2
\end{align}
$$

Hopefully it's clear how you can do a longer version of this computation to compute $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}(A,B)$ for your favorite finitely generated abelian groups $A$ and $B$.

---

But what if $A$ and $B$ are $R$-modules for some PID $R$? Well [remember that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) every finitely generated $R$-module over a PID decomposes as $R^n \oplus \bigoplus_k R/r_k$. Rules $1$, $2$, and $3$ still hold unchanged. So we can split these direct sums in the way we'd like. But what about rules $4$ and $5$? Do they have analogues in the case of general PIDs? Of course they do!

4. $\text{Tor}^R(R,B) \cong 0$ for every $R$-module $B$
5. $\text{Tor}^R(R/r, B) \cong \{ b \in B \mid rb = 0 \}$ for every $R$-module $B$

Note that, $\text{Tor}^R(R/r, B) \cong \{ b \in B \mid rb = 0 \}$ has a natural $R$-module structure, since it's a submodule of $B$.

Lastly, as in the $\mathbb{Z}$ case, $5$ tells us how to compute $\text{Tor}^R(R/r, R/s)$, and thus how to compute $\text{Tor}^R(A,B)$ for any two finitely generated $R$-modules $A$ and $B$. I'll leave this computation to you, though (or to a quick google, if you're so inclined).

(Oh, and there are other properties that I've omitted for the sake of concreteness which are also super helpful for computing $\text{Tor}^R$ in practice, even for non-finitely-generated modules. You can read about them [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tor#RespectForDirectSumsAndFilteredColimits), for instance. The key thing you should have in the back of your head is that even though these definitions *look* extremely complicated, with practice they're often quite routine to compute! So if you can reduce some problem to computing a $\text{Tor}^R$ group, you've practically solved your problem! Hopefully the finitely generated examples in this answer have helped convince you of this.)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is illuminating. However, I believe that $Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,R)$ being an abelian group, and $R$ a ring we may define the scalar multiplication via $r\cdot (x,n,r')=(x,n,r\cdot r')$, where $x\in X, n\in\mathbb{Z}, r'\in R, r\in R$, with $nx=0$ and $nr'=0$ (with the definition given in my question), thus obtaining $Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(X,R)$ an $R$-module. Am I right?